# why am i getting 'Unexpected token" error in jsconfig.json file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

> this is my **jsconfig.json** file in my react app

```
 {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src"   
    },
    "include": ["src"]
 }
```

> this is the error thrown

> > SyntaxError: C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\full_socialMedia_dummy_project\client\jsconfig.json: **Unexpected token** / in JSON at position 57
> > at parse ()

Comment: odd, there is no `/` in that at all

Comment: Well the json you wrote here is valid. So we are missing the wrong JSON you try to parse.

Comment: is it a coincidence that the error is at position 57 and there's exactly 56 characters in that JSON (if you remove white space)

Comment: @JaromandaX why do i count only 55 characters and which white space are referring here to?

Comment: white space ... like space, tab, linefeed etc ... `{"compilerOptions":{"baseUrl":"src"},"include":["src"]}` - and you're right, it's only 55 characters ... my bad - but if the file is laid out as you've shown ... the 57th character is the inner `}` is that the EXACT content?